# CSS how to target background and make it transparent

Tags: css

I am using IE6 and the only occupicy thing i can thing that works is `opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity = 50);`

```
background-color:black;
     opacity: 0.5;
     filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
```

this works but it makes the text transparent as well how can I make only the background colour transparent

Comment: Can you show your code? What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's simple only you have do is to give

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
```

& for IE use this filter

```
{background: transparent;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000)"; /* IE8 */    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000);   /* IE6 & 7 */      zoom: 1;}
```

for more about color transparency in IE you have to read about hsla color:
http://greenevillage.net/csspages/hsla.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at this trick here:

http://randaclay.com/tips-tools/how-to-make-your-backgrounds-transparent-using-css/