# How to make my background opacity 0.7 without affecting the stuff inside it?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs (outer one id = "BD")(inner one id = "content"). I am trying to make the background-color of my BD be less opaque, yet everything inside my content becomes less opaque as well, the images and texts.

How can i solve this?

Comment: How about providing an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ or some source code here?

Comment: there are lots of questions around that deal with this. this is certainly a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Use RGBA.  Here's a [color converter](http://ijk.io/color/convert/) that will convert to RGBA.

This is half opaque white.

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the rgb components for the values of your choice.

```
#bd {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Children inherit opacity. It'd kinda be weird if they didn't. You could use a transparent image for your background, or set the `background-color` of `BD` using `RGBa`. (a = alpha).

[MDN has a great section on `rgba()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba%28%29).

Like so:

```
#BD {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

Just so you're aware though, a lot of times your question will have been asked before and already received some great answers. Its usually a good idea to do a quick search to make sure your question hasn't already been asked.

A quick search of this topic yields [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/css-semi-transparent-background-but-not-text), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565384/how-to-make-the-background-div-only-transparent-using-css?lq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565384/how-to-make-the-background-div-only-transparent-using-css?rq=1), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192993/css-how-to-target-background-and-make-it-transparent?rq=1), for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options:

1. Use `:before`. This allows the use of images ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NJsFg/2/)):

   ```css
   #BD {
       position: relative;
   }
   #BD:before {
       content: '';
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       background: url(http://placehold.it/300);
       opacity: .7;
   }
   ```
2. Use `rgba` and a gradient filter for older IE versions:

   ```css
   #BD {
       background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
       filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bf000000', endColorstr='#bf000000');
   }
   ```

IE gradient uses hex for alpha as well. And it's the first 2 digits. You can use the hex to rgb converter in one of the other answers to figure it out by doing `255 * opacity`, rounding it, and plugging it in for one of the colors.